# While Selecting based on ROWID - Distinct or Group By doesn't work in oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql, logic

I have query like below , I tried to filter out duplicate columns by using Group BY

```
SELECT contacts.rowid      AS ROW_PASS, 
       duty_rota.rowid     AS ROW_PASS_ROTA, 
       duty_rota.duty_type AS DUTY_TYPE 
FROM   duty_rota, 
       duty_types, 
       contacts 
WHERE  duty_rota.duty_type = duty_types.duty_type 
       AND duty_rota.duty_officer = contacts.duty_id 
       AND sname IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY contacts.rowid, 
          duty_rota.rowid, 
          duty_rota.duty_type 
ORDER  BY duty_date
```

After playing with the query little bit I came to know we can't filter out distinct using group by while using ROWID. So can somebody please help me to write code (in SQL) with a logic that

```
if (any row is completely identical with another row of the query o/p)
{
then display only one column
}
```

I will be using the output as gridview's data source in C#, so if not in SQL - can you help me whether somehow in C# I can achieve to display only identical columns?

Comment: Fixed typo in original answer and I added a sqlfiddle answer that you can play with.

Comment: Why have you got ROWIDs in your original query?  It's not standard practice to include them in a projection, so you should state whether your application needs them, as this has a bearing on the solution.

Comment: My friend! whenever you want to remove duplicates one of good ways is to use rowid like this: in where  clause : where rowid =(select max(rowid) from table where "condition which all identical rows included")

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter duplicate rows, you can use this query:

```
SELECT Max(duty_rota.rowid) AS ROW_PASS_ROTA, 
       duty_rota.duty_type  AS DUTY_TYPE 
FROM   duty_rota, 
       duty_types, 
       contacts 
WHERE  duty_rota.duty_type = duty_types.duty_type 
       AND duty_rota.duty_officer = contacts.duty_id 
       AND sname IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY duty_rota.duty_type 
ORDER  BY DUTY_TYPE
```

Comment: Did you run my query friend? it return 2 columns 1st ROW_PASS_ROTA and 2nd DUTY_TYPE,Nothing more

Comment: what is this? : ORDER  BY duty_date I think this causes the error

Comment: you are right friend, i just copy the question query and do some changes on it ,i think that it is true now

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a038/2**

Take out the ROWID's.  Example: If your table has 3 columns (colA, colB, colC) you could find exact row dups this way...

```
select a.* from
(
select count(*) dupCnt, colA, colB, colC from myTable
group by colA, colB, colC
) a
where dupCnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the ROWID is a unique field for each row, so using this field you will never have duplicates. The only solution here is to *not* use it. It's data does not hold anything you would want to display anyway.

Simply put, if you want no duplicates, you need the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, 
                field2 
FROM   table1, 
       table2 
WHERE  table1.key1 = table2.key1;
```

This will select all Field1, Field2 combinations from the two tables. Due to the `DISTINCT` keyword, each line will only be in the result list once. Duplicates will not be in the result list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT duty_rota.duty_type AS DUTY_TYPE 
FROM   duty_rota, 
       duty_types, 
       contacts 
WHERE  duty_rota.duty_type = duty_types.duty_type 
       AND duty_rota.duty_officer = contacts.duty_id 
       AND sname IS NOT NULL 
ORDER  BY duty_date
```

You will only need to `GROUP BY` if you need further operations on the result set, like counting the duplicates. If all you need is "no duplicates", the `DISTINCT` keyword is exactly what you are looking for.

**Edit:**

In case I misread your question and you want to see only those, that *are* duplicates, you need to group and you need to filter based on the *groups* criteria. You can do that using the `HAVING` clause. It's kind of an additional `WHERE` of the groups criteria:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
 WHERE TABLE1.KEY1 = TABLE2.KEY1
 GROUPB BY FIELD1, FIELD2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```